# Updating record with condition Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to update a row in the database that has a certain value as 'position' in Yii.

Now I can use the update() method. But this does not allow me to specify a condition. I am trying to avoid CDbCriteria and native sql to keep my code clean. Does anyone has an advice to update a single record in yii with a condition?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the method `updateAll` ?

> `CActiveRecord::updateAll($attributes, $condition='', $params=array())`
>
> Updates records with the specified condition.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> *array*
> $attributes -
> list of attributes (name=>$value) to be updated
> mixed
>
>  $condition -
> query condition or criteria
>
> *array*
> $params
> parameters to be bound to an SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

updateAll is a method in CActiveRecord, and it lets you specify conditions http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail

Comment: Thanks! How do I translate this to fit in this method. Im stuck..
array(
   'position'=>$_GET['position']++,
  
   'condition'=>array(
     'position'=>$_GET['position'],
     'sidebar_id'=>$_GET['sid']
    )
   )